# With Gmail's 2-step verification, what's the purpose of the "recovery email address"?

Tags: google-account, security, passwords, account-recovery

If I have a change in phone number, and the two-step stops working, is the recovery email address going to be all it takes to get back full access, or is that only going to be useful for a forgotten password?

I ask this because I am not sure I like the backup options available for the two-step deal, but I do have an email address that is plenty secure, and I am OK using it for full recovery options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the alternate email address cannot give you full access over your own account in case you lose your phone. The email address is only for additional protection for users signed up for 2-step verification.